# how to change the UIWebView background

Tags: uiwebview

How to change the default gray background color of UIWebView to an image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can set the background image:

```
 self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]];
```